# Change Cisco Management VLAN

Tags: firewall, cisco, vlan, checkpoint

I currently have the following configuration. A Checkpoint firewall (which is the router) and 12 Cisco 9200 switches. SW1 is connected to the firewall. I need to change the MGMT VLAN from VLAN20 to VLAN95. On the firewall, the interfaces act as  gateway for each VLANs on the network, and are defined as follows:

- MGMT - 192.168.2.254 (VLAN20)
- eth2 - 192.168.3.254 (VLAN30)
  ...
- eth6.70 - 192.168.7.254 (VLAN70)
- eth8 - 192.168.9.254 (VLAN90)
- ip default gateway 192.168.2.254 - on all switches, VLAN20 is the MGMT Interface

All VLANs are defined on all switches, but only VLAN20 has an IP address on "interface Vlan20", on all switches.
All trunk ports on the Cisco switches allow traffic from all VLANs.
The only switch that has 2 IP addresses is SW1, which is directly connected to the firewall:

- interface Vlan20
  ip address 192.168.2.245 255.255.255.0
- interface Vlan 70
  ip address 192.168.7.230 255.255.255.0
  So far so good, I can ping all gateway IP addresses (*.254) from any switch and from all device on the network.

Now to the problem.
I have assigned the IP address 192.168.95.254 to eth5 on the firewall and added VLAN95 and "interface Vlan95" on each switch, but without assigning IP addresses to "interface Vlan95".

- eth5 - 192.168.95.254 (VLAN95)
  At this point, I can ping 192.168.95.254 from any of the Cisco switches.
  But as soon as I assign a Vlan95 IP address to any of the switches (let's say SW1, interface Vlan 95 - IP address 192.168.95.240 255.255.255.0), I cannot ping 192.168.95.254 from SW1 anymore. 
  Also, I cannot ping 192.168.95.240 from the firewall itself.
  So, I can ping the firewall interface 192.168.95.254 from SW1 with this switch configuration:
- interface Vlan20
  ip address 192.168.2.245 255.255.255.0
- interface Vlan70
  ip address 192.168.7.230 255.255.255.0
- **interface Vlan95

  no ip address**

but not with this configuration:

- interface Vlan20
  ip address 192.168.2.245 255.255.255.0
- interface Vlan70
  ip address 192.168.7.230 255.255.255.0
- **interface Vlan95

  ip address 192.168.95.240 255.255.255.0**

What I don't understand is why I cannot ping 192.168.95.240 (SW1, interface Vlan95) from the firewall.

"route -n" output from the firewall:
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 Mgmt
192.168.3.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth2
192.168.4.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth6.40
192.168.6.240   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.240 U     0      0        0 eth4
192.168.7.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth6.70
192.168.9.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth8
192.168.95.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth5
192.168.96.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth6.96

And "show ip route" from SW1:

Gateway of last resort is 192.168.2.254 to network 0.0.0.0

S*    0.0.0.0/0 [0/0] via 192.168.2.254
192.168.2.0/24 is variably subnetted, 2 subnets, 2 masks
C        192.168.2.0/24 is directly connected, Vlan20
L        192.168.2.245/32 is directly connected, Vlan20
192.168.7.0/24 is variably subnetted, 2 subnets, 2 masks
C        192.168.7.0/24 is directly connected, Vlan70
L        192.168.7.230/32 is directly connected, Vlan70
192.168.95.0/24 is variably subnetted, 2 subnets, 2 masks
C        192.168.95.0/24 is directly connected, Vlan95
L        192.168.95.240/32 is directly connected, Vlan95

I am missing something for sure, not sure what. Any ideas welcome.

Answer (score 0):

From the route -n command it looks like the firewall isn't adding the VLAN tag so is that interface plugged into an access port on SW1? If so is that access port in the right VLAN?

Before you added the VLAN 95 SVI any traffic destined for that network was going through your default gateway. With an interface in VLAN 95 traffic destined to that interface is just going to try and resolve via arp and do nothing else. Confirm that eth6 and VLAN 95 are in the same broadcast domain.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).